# Output more than one excel/csv file from a class. OOP. Class Inheritance

Tags: python, dataframe, oop, inheritance, tuples

I am getting a AttributeError as follows:

```
self.filtered_df.to_excel(self.output_filepath, index=False)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I am inheriting a class for another class I am developing, currently the inheritance allows me to output one excel file, can I change the method in this class to allow me to output more than one excel file in the new class I am developing?

Here is the class, inherited:

```
class ReportQueryCommand(LogCommand):
    """Performs reports through a ReportQueryStrategy instance.

    It is possible to overwrite existing queries; this means that it is possible
    to perform subsequent filters by launching multiple commands having
    key_input = strategy.name.

    Attributes:
        state: DatasetState containing so-far computed DataFrames.
        strategy: defines how to perform the query.
        filepath: optional. Defines where to save the queried DataFrame.
        key_input: optional (None if df_to_filter is not None).
            Defines a key that allows to access a DataFrame in the State.
        df_to_filter: optional (None if key is not None).
            DataFrame to apply the query on.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 strategy: ReportQueryStrategy,
                 base_path: Optional[str] = None,
                 key_input: Optional[str] = None,
                 key_output: Optional[str] = None,
                 df_to_filter: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None,
                 filepath: Optional[str] = None,
                 directory_path: Optional[str] = None,
                 write_output: bool = True):
        super().__init__(base_path=base_path,
                         directory_path=directory_path,
                         copy_before_update=False,
                         write_output=write_output)
        self.state = DatasetState()
        self.strategy = strategy
        self.filepath = filepath

        self.key_input = key_input
        self._key_output = key_output
        self.df_to_filter = df_to_filter
        self.filtered_df = None

    @property
    def _output_file(self) -> str:
        return self.strategy.output_filename

    def write_to_file(self):
        if self.filtered_df is None:
            raise ValueError("Missing computed dataframe")
        self.filtered_df.to_excel(self.output_filepath, index=False)

    @property
    def key_output(self) -> str:
        # first scenario: key was defined
        if self._key_output is not None:
            return self._key_output
        # second scenario: key was not defined, by default,
        # concatenate key_input and strategy
        strategy_output_name = self.strategy.output_name
        if self.key_input is not None:
            return f"{self.key_input}-{strategy_output_name}"
        # WCS: no key defined, just assign the strategy key
        return strategy_output_name

    def execute(self, output_from_previous: Any = None, **kwargs) -> Any:
        self.filtered_df = self.strategy.transform(key=self.key_input,
                                                   df=self.df_to_filter)
        self.state.query_reports[self.key_output] = self.filtered_df
        super().execute(output_from_previous=output_from_previous, **kwargs)
```

As you can see here the method I need to update is 'def write_to_file(self):'

Here is snippets of the relevant code in development to show where this problems 'could be occuring'. The following bits of code below are relevant, this might need to be updated to allow me to output two excel files or more:

```
class TtestStrategy(ReportQueryStrategy):
    """
    """

    @staticmethod
    def _strategy_key():
        return 't-test', 'fisher-test'

    def __init__(self,
                 query_name: Optional[str] = None,
                 reference_query: str = None,
                 sample_query: str = None,
                 alpha: float = 0.05,
                 chemical_key: str = 'chemical',
                 plate_key: str = 'plate',
                 value_key: str = 'processed_relative_fp',
                 group_column: str = 'Lot',
                 return_pivoted: bool = True):
        super().__init__(query_name=query_name)
        self.pvalues = []
        self.alpha = alpha

        self.chemical_key, self.plate_key, self.value_key, self.reference_query, self.sample_query = (chemical_key,
                                                                                                      plate_key,
                                                                                                      value_key,
                                                                                                      reference_query,
                                                                                                      sample_query)
        self.group_column = group_column
        self.return_pivoted = return_pivoted
    

    def fishers_method(self, pvalues) -> tuple[bool, float, float, float]:               
        pvalues = [item for item in pvalues if not pd.isnull(item)]     
        comb_z, comb_pval = stats.combine_pvalues(pvalues, method="fisher")       
      
        k = len(pvalues)        
        mean_FDR = (self.alpha * (k + 1)) / (2 * k)        
       
        if comb_pval > mean_FDR:
            decision = False
        else:
            decision = True

        return decision, comb_z, comb_pval, mean_FDR

    def transform(self,
                  key: Optional[str] = None,
                  df: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None) -> tuple[Any, DataFrame]:
        counter_nosig = 0
        counter_sig_st_t = 0
        pval_store_st_t = {}
        pval_store_st_t_dec = {}
        pval_store_st_t_val = {}
        pval_store_st_t_val_adj = {}
        pval_store_norm_A = {}
        pval_store_norm_B = {}
        var_store_A = {}
        var_store_B = {}
        pval_store_lev_bart = {}
        decisions = []
        st_pval_arr = []

        df = super().transform(key=key, df=df)
        
        df = df.loc[(df[self.group_column] == self.reference_query) | (df[self.group_column] == self.sample_query)]
        df_i = df.filter(['plate', 'chemical', 'processed_relative_fp'], axis=1)
        df_i = df.pivot(columns='plate', values='processed_relative_fp', index='chemical')
        df_i.index.name = None
        df_i.columns.name = ''
        
        plates = {exps: {"processed_relative_fp": series}
                  for exps, series in df_i.to_dict("series").items()}
        chem_order = list(df['chemical'].unique())
        for chem in chem_order:
            if chem != 'empty':
                pool = []                
                sample_l = []

                for q in [self.reference_query, self.sample_query]:                    
                    sample = pd.Series([sample for sample in plates])
                    sample = sample[sample.str.contains(q)]
                    
                    for s in sample:
                        sample_l.append(s)                       

                        record = plates[s]                      
                        
                        if record['processed_relative_fp'] is not None:
                            rel_fp = record['processed_relative_fp']                           
                           
                            lot = s.split("_")[1]
                            cell = s.split('_')[2]
                            rep = s.split("_")[4]                            
                            
                            val = rel_fp[chem]
                            
                            pool.append({"chems": chem, "lot": lot, "cell": cell, "replicate": rep,
                                         "key": chem + "::" + lot + "::" + rep + "::" + cell, "value": val})

                
                pool = pd.DataFrame(pool)                

                massage = []
                averages = []
                sort_lots = list(pool['lot'].unique())
                for lot in sort_lots:
                    value = list(pool[pool.lot.eq(lot)]['value'].dropna())                    
                    averages.append(np.mean(np.array(value)))
                    massage.append(value)                    

                
                averages = np.array(averages)
                min_ = np.nanmin(averages)
                max_ = np.nanmax(averages)
                pos_min_ = np.where(averages == min_)[0][0]
                pos_max_ = np.where(averages == max_)[0][0]
                perc_diff = (max_ - min_) * 100
                
                fvalue_st_t, pvalue_st_t = stats.ttest_ind(*massage, equal_var=False)                

                
                st_pval_arr.append(pvalue_st_t)
                st_pval_array = np.asarray(st_pval_arr)
                mask = np.isfinite(st_pval_array)
                st_t_t_pval_adj = np.empty(st_pval_array.shape)
                st_t_t_pval_adj.fill(np.nan)
                rej_st_t, st_t_t_pval_adj[mask], _, _ = sm.stats.multipletests(st_pval_array[mask], method='fdr_bh')

                for v in st_t_t_pval_adj:
                    float(v)
                    pval_store_st_t_val_adj[chem] = v
                    
                for z in rej_st_t:
                    float(z)
                
                if len(massage[0]) >= 3:
                    test_stat_norm_A, pvalue_norm_A = stats.shapiro(np.array(massage[0]))
                    if pvalue_norm_A < 0.05:
                        pval_store_norm_A[chem] = 'No'
                    else:
                        pval_store_norm_A[chem] = 'Yes'
                else:
                    pval_store_norm_A[chem] = 'Not enough data'

                if len(massage[1]) >= 3:
                    test_stat_norm_B, pvalue_norm_B = stats.shapiro(np.array(massage[1]))
                    if pvalue_norm_B < 0.05:
                        pval_store_norm_B[chem] = 'No'
                    else:
                        pval_store_norm_B[chem] = 'Yes'
                else:
                    pval_store_norm_B[chem] = 'not enough data'

                
                var_stat_A = stats.variation(np.array(massage[0]))
                var_stat_B = stats.variation(np.array(massage[1]))

                
                stat_lev_bart, pvalue_lev_bart = stats.levene(*massage, center='mean')                

               
                pval_store_st_t[chem] = pvalue_st_t

                pval_store_st_t_val[chem] = pvalue_st_t
                
                var_store_A[chem] = var_stat_A
                var_store_B[chem] = var_stat_B
                
                pval_store_lev_bart[chem] = pvalue_lev_bart
                
                if pvalue_st_t < 0.05:
                    pval_store_st_t[chem] = 'diff'
                else:
                    pval_store_st_t[chem] = 'same'
                
                if v > 0.05:
                    pval_store_st_t_dec[chem] = 'same'
                
                if v < 0.05 and perc_diff > 0.0:
                    pval_store_st_t_dec[chem] = 'diff'                    
                    counter_sig_st_t += 1

                else:                    
                    counter_nosig += 1
        
        decisions.append(pval_store_st_t)        
        decisions.append(pval_store_st_t_dec)        
        decisions.append(pval_store_st_t_val)        
        decisions.append(pval_store_st_t_val_adj)        
        decisions.append(pval_store_norm_A)
        decisions.append(pval_store_norm_B)        
        decisions.append(var_store_A)
        decisions.append(var_store_B)        
        decisions.append(pval_store_lev_bart)
        decisions = pd.DataFrame(decisions)
        decisions = decisions.T
        decisions.columns = [
            f'Welchs t-test result for lot {self.reference_query} v lot {self.sample_query}',
            'Welchs t-test considering Multi-test Correction',
            'Welchs t-test pvalue unadjusted',
            'Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted',
            f'are lot {self.reference_query} chemicals normally distributed?',
            f'are lot {self.sample_query} chemicals normally distributed?',
            f'lot {self.reference_query} variance',
            f'lot {self.sample_query} variance',
            'levenes statistic']        
        decisions_before_filter = decisions.copy()
        decisions_before_filter.reset_index(inplace=True)
        decisions_before_filter.rename(columns={'index': 'chemicals'}, inplace=True)
        decisions = decisions.loc[(decisions['Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted'] < self.alpha)]

        decisions.reset_index(inplace=True)
        decisions.rename(columns={'index': 'chemicals'}, inplace=True)
        decisions.sort_values(by=['Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted'], inplace=True)

        decisions_before_filter = decisions_before_filter.filter(items=['chemicals', 'Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted'])
        decisions_before_filter = decisions_before_filter.sort_values(by=['Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted'])
        
        results_fishers = self.fishers_method(decisions_before_filter['Welchs t-test pvalue adjusted'].tolist())
        results_fishers_df = pd.DataFrame(results_fishers,
                                          index=['decision',
                                                 'combined z-score',
                                                 'combined p-value',
                                                 'meanFDR'])
        results_fishers_df = results_fishers_df.T
        results_fishers_df['k'] = len(decisions_before_filter.dropna())
        results_fishers_df.insert(loc=0, column='comparison', value=(str(self.reference_query + '-' + 'vs'
                                                                         + '-' + self.sample_query)))

        return decisions, results_fishers_df
```

See all the information above

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `filtered_df` is **NOT** a `pandas.DataFrame`.

It's a `tuple`. In fact your `TtestStrategy`'s `transform` method returns the tuple:

```
    return decisions, results_fishers_df
```

If you change your code to:

```
def execute(self, output_from_previous: Any = None, **kwargs) -> Any:
    _ignored, self.filtered_df = self.strategy.transform(key=self.key_input,
                                               df=self.df_to_filter)
    self.state.query_reports[self.key_output] = self.filtered_df
    super().execute(output_from_previous=output_from_previous, **kwargs)
```

then you shouldn't see that `AttributeError` anymore.

Comment: @Bakuiru, this wasn't the error. The error was 
'''
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
'''

I traced it back to the method 'def wrtie_to_file(self)' in the ReportQueryCommand class

Comment: @Paddy_1916 The problem is the same. You are setting `filtered_df` to a tuple and then you are trying to call `pandas.DataFrame` methods on it. If you try my suggestion you will see that error disappear (assuming that's the only place where `filtered_df` is set).